# Is GraphicDesign.SE a good fit for my questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I am looking for a site where I could ask questions concerning Poster or slideshow(powerpoint) presentation.

I have non-technical, often opinion-based questions such as:

- I want to represent two fish species by two logos. One species is a competitor (which means blabla…), one species is a disperser (which means blablabla..). I was thinking of Hercule and Sonic, what do you think?  (I actually recently asked this question on GraphicDesign.SE and it has been judged off-topic and has been downvoted)
- Is it wise to always use the same graphic design for each presentation so that people get used to a given style or would it be better to change the design so that people don't get bored.
- Do you have any idea how to graphically explain, on one powerpoint slide, the concept of <*something*>.
- Does everybody knows the characters of Pinky and the Brain so that I can use them in a presentation without having to tell how they behaviorally differ
- How would you improve this slide (with a picture of the slide). Because the problems of this slide are this and that.

or slightly more technical questions of the kind:

- What four colors would give the greatest contrast on a blue background

Is GraphicDesign a good site for these questions? Is there another StackExchange website where I could ask these questions? If not, do you know another Q&A websites where I could get good answers to these questions?

---

I'm sorry, the question I am asking here is probably off-topic but there is nowhere I can ask it otherwise and I bet you guys from Graphic Design Community would probably be quite good at answering it.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to represent two fish species by two logos. One species is a competitor (which means blabla…), one species is a disperser (which means blablabla..). I was thinking of Hercule and Sonic, what do you think? (I actually recently asked this question on GraphicDesign.SE and it has been judged off-topic and has been downvoted)

You already have your answer on this one.

> Is it wise to always use the same graphic design for each presentation so that people get used to a given style or would it be better to change the design so that people don't get bored.

This question currently would probably get mixed response but a simple edit could make it much more likely to stay open. Basically, reword it to something along the lines of **"When should I change my design or brand to keep things interesting at the risk of decreasing some recognition?"**

Or possibly **"How do I find a balance across an entire advertising campaign between brand recognition and keeping things up-to-date and modern?"**

Those would both then need to also state what you've tried and where you're struggling. Think the second one also has similar questions already on the site.

> Do you have any idea how to graphically explain, on one powerpoint slide, the concept of .

Absolutely not and would be closed pretty much instantly. It doesn't really help anyone else, shows a lack of effort, and is kinda asking us to do your job and/or homework for you.

> Does everybody knows the characters of Minus and Cortex so that I can use it in a presentation without having to tell how they behaviorally differ

This is a tough one in my opinion and will depend on the wording. On the one hand the character usage is extremely narrow on the other hand you don't mention audience. There's probably a way to get into this topic but I'm not sure this is it.

*And for the record: I've got no idea who Minus and Cortex are*

> How would you improve this slide (with a picture of the slide). Because the problems of this slide are this and that.

As long as you include the `this` and `that` this could stay open under our current FAQ as far as I know.

> What four colors would give the greatest contrast on a blue background?

This would be okay but might be closed for lack of research. Pretty sure you could find that out easily enough with a google search. If you do that search, find some options but don't agree with them or think its wrong information that could be a more interesting question.

---

You can always join us in our chatroom [The Ink Spot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) we get a fairly good crowd in there and its more open to just discussion and banter. For some of these questions especially about audience you could ask on a Marketing forum, I'm following the [Proposed Marketing - StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51786/marketing) and would encourage you to do so as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a translation issue. Minus and Cortex are called [Pinky and the Brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinky_and_the_Brain) in english! Sorry for the mistake, I corrected it.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the first question about the fishes and the logos. It is a question that asks for ideas and creativity. Is it on topic?

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts pretty much echo Ryan's, so I'll just focus on the ones I think *could* work on our site:

> Is it wise to always use the same graphic design for each presentation so that people get used to a given style or would it be better to change the design so that people don't get bored.

I think this question could spark some interesting discussion, but the important factor to include is who you're asking it as. Are you asking it as a student giving presentations? As a teacher giving lectures? As a salesman pitching products? As a company issuing seminars?

Without some sort of context, the answer could be anything. Focusing the scope of the question will keep it grounded.

> How would you improve this slide (with a picture of the slide). Because the problems of this slide are this and that.

This sounds like a critique question. We allow critiques, but they have to follow a tight format to provide a solid platform for providing constructive answers. The most important part is to give us something to objectively judge.

We're not looking for "How can I make this slide look prettier?", we're looking for "Does is size of the footer in this PowerPoint template a distraction from the content?". Try and keep it one-dimensional.

For more information on that, see this meta post: [**What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/8708)