# Can we ask here a question about reviewing a logo or a banner etc ...?

Tags: discussion, design

I haven't found a definitive answer about this subject in the [help](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) section so I'm asking here :

Can we ask a question that asks for reviewing a graphic design whether it is good or not ?

Comment: Opinion based questions could be sometimes on topic. Place the picture and ask specific questions + what are your doubts?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've asked the question and I'll see how it goes ! http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28871/can-this-design-be-considered-as-a-banner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description here, it sounds like you have in mind what we call a critique question. They're on-topic, but with some criteria. Check out this meta question for more information: [**What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/8708).

However, [the question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/28871/8708) you've posted isn't really what I consider a critique question. You're asking about a specific graphic that you're working with, yet Ryan's answer is broad enough that it can be re-applied to different scenarios. Either way, I think the question is right at home here.

Comment: Okay cool, thank you !