# SE: Graphic Design - appropriate for interface design review?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I'm a web developer and interface designer, and for the improvement of my development structure and practice, I can go to SE's Code Review. However, even more than I focus on the quality of back-end design, I focus, in extreme-detail, on developing the best possible user interface for the software. Not just something to get the job done, but truly inspirational, beautiful, interactive user interface built to satisfy the consumer at every level.

---

I can ask opinions and reviews of these interfaces from clients, family, and friends, but I feel that while they like the interfaces, they aren't able to give the high level review/ criticism that might help me to improve my practices further.

---

- I'm wondering if this site is a place where it would be appropriate for me to request these reviews, similar to the way code quality is reviewed in detail on Code Review.
- If not, maybe there is another site known for this by the design community?

---

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I just realized that this probably belongs in Meta; can it be moved, or should I delete and re-post? I don't have the 5 points necessary to post in Meta.

Comment: I'm about to move it for you, but for future reference you can flag it for moderator attention!

Comment: Thanks, and noted! @JohnB

Comment: Have you asked at UX.SE? I'd be curious how they handle this.

Comment: I'll do so, now that you mention it. @Scott

Comment: @Scott: [Question on UX SE](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/1615/17023).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I break it down:

- Graphic Design is for How it Looks (bodywork and finish)
- User Experience is for How it Works (cockpit and control layout)
- Code Review is for What Makes it Work (engine, frame and moving parts)

There's certainly some overlap -- UX might spill over into either of the others -- but that's the rough division.

What an object should look like is GD. Where it should go on the page could be UX or GD. What it should do when it gets there is UX. And how best to make it do that is for Code Review.

Comment: That is an excellent answer. Here, for example, I might request a critique of the color-scheme, style, and superficial/inspirational value, while I use UX to request a review of user interactivity, productivity, navigation, and general layout technique. Then of course code review for whatever's under the hood.

Comment: That's the way I see it, yes.

Comment: Excellent summary. For most web devs life is an overlapping of the three :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is on-topic for either here or UX.... And my personal opinion is, if it follows the critique guidelines, ([What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)) I wouldn't see an issue here myself.