# What is a good comment to leave for closed critiques?

Tags: discussion

We get a lot of critiques questions and I always wonder what would be the best way to not scare off a new user but leave a comment that will encourage them to edit their question after it has been closed in regards to not being in scope.  So, I would like to know what you guys think and suggest for adding a comment to a closed critique question?

Answer (score 1):

> "Requests for critiques must include either a specific question about your design or specific guidelines for the critique. See: What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?"

I think the above is good and should be an auto-comment (Similar to "possible duplicate") for that close reason.  It could possibly be expanded upon...

> "Thanks for the question! In order to assist users in providing you with valuable feedback, requests for critiques must include either a **specific** question about your design or **specific** guidelines for the critique. See: [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/8708)" It's difficult for users to answer questions which ask for a general review."

(Note worked the words "feedback" and "review" in there as well for SEO :) )