# Is a question about optimizing user interface on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have made dialog box that hosts a lot of various controls ( around 50 ) using C++ and raw WinAPI.

Although my application works, I still wish to somehow reduce the number of controls I use in a dialog box. I wish to ask on GraphicDesign for help, so I first wanted to check here if this type of question is on topic?

If it isn't can you suggest me SE network that could help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Matt's answer, your question can live on both sites, it just depends on what sort of answers you are looking for. Over **UX.SE** they will focus more on **interaction** and information architecture. Here in **GD.SE** you will get answers related to **visual improvements**.

You can ask on both sites, as long as you phrase your questions differently so they focus on either usability or graphics.

Don't forget to add screenshots of what you currently have, answers will be much more detailed if we can see an image.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed, I need improvements for user interaction as 50 controls is just too much ( the entire dialog box occupies entire 17 inch screen which is just bad ). Visual improvements are of secondary nature, so I think my chances are better on UX.SE. Thanks for clarifying things for me, best regards :)

Answer (score 1):

We do have a site called [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) that might allow your question.  If you want the question to live on GD you could tag it [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) but we do have a [requirement on how to write a critique question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).

Comment: Thank you, I will post this same question on the site you recommended. I am reading about critique questions at the moment. Maybe I can phrase my question to fit. Thank you for your time. Best regards.