# Can I ask for information graphics review and suggestions?

Tags: discussion, critique

We are working on a figure that is trying to present some complex information in a clear meaningful way. Would GraphicDesign be the place to get suggestions on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

General idea gathering/brainstorming questions are likely to get closed as either opinion based or too broad, but it isn't clear cut—there certainly are some idea gathering questions that go down ok. If you are going to ask such a question try and limit its scope and present a specific problem you need to solve.

If you are wanting critique on your work these are ok but there are some guidlines to follow:

- **[What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/52050)**

Questions along the lines of "How does this look?" will be closed. If you can limit your question to a specific issue and word it in a way that is likely to help future readers then you should be ok. Have a look through some of the example questions in the guidelines to get an idea of what is and isn't acceptable.