# Are questions about the rationale behind a design choice on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've read both [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/26474) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and it seems that this kind of question is fine. What do you think?

Below is my draft:

> ## What make this design be suitable to use for poetry texts?
>
> This is how WordPress designs a block of verse:
>
> [image]
>
> Honestly I don't know how to provide more information. Why does that design suit poetry texts?

[What make this design suitable to use for poetry texts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/127508/26474)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... What aspect of the design do you refer to? If this is a question about a WordPress theme, you are better off emailing the designer of the theme

Comment: I mean, why can that combination of typography, spacing, border reflect the poetry effect? It doesn't seem to belong to a specific WordPress theme, but any theme. So I'd like to have an analysis why/how the poetry effect is conveyed with this design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with asking about the rationale behind a single entity is that it's not likely to be documented enough to be answerable by someone else than the original designers.

Also, some may recall there used to be a close reason for asking a question that is "too localized". These questions are not likely to be answerable and useful to others. This question falls into the "too localized" category as far as I'm concerned.

## BUT

I think it would be on-topic (and more likely answerable) if the question asked about **a body of works** instead of a **single one**.

For example, [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122306/why-is-the-design-of-haulage-companies-so-special) has some similarities but is applicable to multiple instances in a common field and is well documented.

I'm pretty sure asking ***"Why are most poetry works typically laid out with sober type and a lot of white space?"*** would yield interesting and useful answers.

Other related questions:
[Why is Courier the preferred font in the legal industry?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128175/why-is-courier-the-preferred-font-in-the-legal-industry)

Comment: I see. So the only thing I need is to add more examples of this rather than just one.

Comment: Well it salvages the question, but it also changes it and only you know if you need this specific information about WordPress. I know I could take an informed guess if it was worded with multiple examples. Please note also that the example question was displayed on Hot Network Questions so the 20 upvotes are probably a bit from all over the place and not just GDSE.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find out is to post your question and see if the community closes it or not. Just don't take it personally.

I strongly suspect this would be closed. It's been a while since such a question were asked so I could be wrong. However, in the past when a question like this was asked the response is, "We are not the designers. We don't know their motives and rationale. You would need to ask them."

---

In a critique question we ask users to mention what their goal is and then help make sure the design achieves that. This is not that at all, in fact its the opposite. You're giving us a finished design and asking us to determine what the goal is. It would be like me painting a big red circle just off-center on an otherwise blank canvas -- showing it to you -- and asking you to tell me the meaning behind the piece

Comment: do you see it similar to a critique request question? I think it is, and thus should be welcomed. I just want to be careful

Comment: @Ooker updated my answer for you

Comment: I see your point. When I crafted this question, I thought more about why the design achieved the goal of reflecting the poetry ambience. So how about this: I post my own design for this, asking for critique, and give this image as an example of a final product. What do you think?

Comment: @Ooker as long as your question clearly states a goal and is answerable

Comment: Thinking about your analogy, I think it's not about asking for the meaning, but about giving the meaning of it (that the artist says it themself), and asking why it represents that meaning. Do you think it states a clear goal and answerable?

Comment: @Ooker I gave my opinion and really don't have much more to say. I'm just one voice. Ask your question, see what others think. Just please remember if it is negative not to take it personally. If it is positive -- take it as personally as you'd like! :)

Comment: well, if you are still disagreeing with it, but unable to say more, then probably there is some [tacit knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_knowledge) in you. If you can find a way to describe it, then everyone will be benefit :D

Comment: @Ooker Fellow fan of Polanyi here :)

Comment: @Emilie I'm not familiar with his work. Can you explain?

Comment: @ooker He coined the term tacit knowledge and wrote about it

Answer (score -2):

I see the proposed question is exactly the same with the forth example in [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/26474):

> Good Example: "Does the piece convey an air of playfulness and excitement?"
>   Bad Example: "What impression do you get?"

So I would vote it's on-topic.