# Post your Work In Progress (FKA: The Looking Glass)

Tags: discussion, critique

This is a community wiki where you can post things you're working on and others can comment. Because it is a community wiki there is no expectation of rep or answers.

Please only post your own work here.

For specific critique questions users are still welcomed and encouraged to create them as separate questions with the [critique](/questions/tagged/critique) tag following our [Critique Guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).

For those that really just want to post their image and ask for comments though, this is a more visible and permanent solution than our current [Looking Glass](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass).

Please still use either The Looking Glass or a new chatroom for any lengthy discussions about a particular piece.

---

**Personal Copyright Notice**

Using the Image Upload gives your work a public Creative Commons license. To avoid this upload the image to your own website or host and hotlink to it (embed the image using the link from wherever you have the image hosted).

If you do this then it has been advised to indicate that the image is Copyright protected.

Comment: It *might* be beneficial to point out CC license attribution to *anything* posted and how to circumvent that in many instances. I.E. I'd never post most of my work because I don't want to attribute a CC license to it. But, one can *link* to  work to avoid that.

Comment: Meta Post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309025/is-my-copyrighted-artwork-protected-if-i-upload-it-to-a-post  That may offer some stuff to yank from :) Note you *can't* use the built in imgr.com hosting and then a link.... it does the *same thing* and attributes the CC licensing.

Answer (score 8):

I have absolutely no time for typesetting right now so this isn't much of a work in progress, but just to break the ice, here's a picture of a favorite quote of mine after I was done typesetting it :)

[image]

Comment: So many letters you have. very hard to come by where I live. Must have been all thrown out.

Comment: @Wolff Oh they are not mine :) (and there were way, way more letters!) It was produced at a local letterpress museum, where you can buy time and make your own prints.

Answer (score 5):

Blood Orange

> [image: Blood Orange]